# PHP explode string using a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a long string consisting of a series of sentences separated by a single quote.

Example:

```
This\'s sentence number 1'This\'s sentence number 2'
```

Notice that the string has single quotes part of the sentence itself which are escaped. I need to explode the string using single quote, but not the escaped single quote.

The output should be:

```
Array{
      [0]=>This\'s sentence number 1
      [1]=>This\'s sentence number 2
}
```

Basically I need to explode the string on { ' }, but not { \' }.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `ending with backslash\\'s uiae`?

Comment: @knitti I have no control on the provided string. I just need to parse it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```jphp
print_r(preg_split("/(?<!\\\)\'/", "This\'s sentence number 1'This\'s sentence number 2'"));
```