# One explode function for two date formats

Tags: php

I have two PHP variable  `$consult_date_arr` and `$consultationdate`.the user can insert any date format consider for now 22-12-2014 or 22/12/2014.what i want to do is i want to write a explode function which should work for both the condition i.e. for both the date formats.

```
$consult_date_arr=explode("/",$consultationdate);
$consult_date_arr=explode("-",$consultationdate);
```

The explode function should be the combination of above two explode function in functionality,such date it works for both the formats.if any doubt please let me know.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using strtotime first and then exploding.

Comment: @SurabhilSergy please elaborate.

Comment: why don't u have a validation on users input?it saves ur time

Comment: @SuhelMeman cant do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP explode string using a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908054/php-explode-string-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: What if the user enters 22.12.14 or 22nd December 2014 or 12/22/14 or 22 12 14 or December 22 2014 or 2014-12-22 or.... I think you get my meaning by now.

Comment: @vascowhite you are absolutely write,i have to take care of that also.

Comment: @RishabhRaj You can convert the dates to a common format using strtotime function and then explode it for further use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $dt = "1992-05-30";
    //$dt = "1992/05/30";
    function expld($date){
        $date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);
        $date = explode("-",$date);
        return $date;
    }
    $newdate = expld($dt);
    echo $newdate[0];

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
    <?php
        $date = '22/12/2014';
        $keywords = preg_split("/[-,\/]+/", $date);
        print_r($keywords);
    ?>
```

> preg_split — Split string by a regular expression

REFERENCE

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Answer (score 1):

you can write custom function and call explode inside it

like 
$string = "-" OR "/" Or whatever you want to explode with

```
function dateFormat($string,$date)
{
   $consult_date_arr=explode($string,$consultationdate);
   return  $consult_date_arr;
}
```

Comment: thank for the reply but as i mentioned in the question that i am not sure which date format the user will use so i cant assign that to $string and i dont want to use an extra function for that.

Comment: you can find separator by finding its position in given date

Comment: vishal : how to do that?

Comment: $date = "15-01-2010";
$string = substr($date, 2,1);

Answer (score 1):

you will need regular expression, using `preg_match` in php.

```
<?php
$consult_date_arr;
$consultationdate = '22/12/2014';
if(preg_match('/[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{4}/', $consultationdate)){
$consult_date_arr = explode('-', $consultationdate);
}else if(preg_match('/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}/', $consultationdate)){
    $consult_date_arr = explode('/', $consultationdate);
}
var_dump($consult_date_arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi check the code below,

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('date_explode')){
function date_explode($date){
    $explode_date = array();
    $delimiter    = '';
    if(strstr($date, '/')){
        $delimiter = '/';
    }elseif(strstr($date, '-')){
        $delimiter = '-';
    }
    if(!empty($delimiter)){
        $explode_date = explode($delimiter, $date);
    }
    return $explode_date;
}   
}

$consult_date_arr=date_explode('22-12-2014');
print_r($consult_date_arr);
$consult_date_arr=date_explode('22/12/2014');
print_r($consult_date_arr);
?>
```

[fiddle example](http://codepad.org/p3DOmYUl)

P.S.: Please do validation its a must, validation will prevent you from this type of issues